# How to create SSH Key for git user

Tags: ssh, sync, git, repository, hook

If i want to syncronize my remote origin with another remote repository i will have to register a post-update hook. But I will need an ssh key for that.

Because my origin repo is owned by git user, i will need to create that ssh for that user. But i can not login as git user to create the need ssh keys (gitlab created that user and i do not know a password). Is there another approach to do that sync, or is there a general mistake in the way i want to do that?

Comment: You could log in as root and then `su - git` right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have root/sudo privilege you can create the key and then store in the git user's `.ssh` directory. Don't forget to `chown` the created to file so they belong to `git:git` and `chmod` them to the appropriate paranoid values.